# how unset or delete some nested array in $_SESSION

Tags: php, arrays, session, array-unset

I have some items in shop basket in `SESSION`.

Each item maybe be for one shop and another item maybe for another shop.

I want when customer click in create factor button for each shop item list in basket.
How can I delete or unset some items in my basket that have same `shopid` and customer click create factor for this shop with this `shopid`.

My session array for example is:

```
Array('customer' => Array('basket' => Array(
                    '9_2' => Array
                        (
                            "row" => "0",
                            'item' => 'cd',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '1391-12-25 19:27:56',
                            'sale_end_date' => '1392-04-20 19:27:49',
                            'sale_price' => '40500',
                            'price' => '54564',
                            'id' => '999035',
                            'shopid' => '4'
                        ),
                        '999_17' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '1',
                            'item' => 'car',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '6'
                        ),
                        '9_3' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '2',
                            'item' => 'book',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '4'
                        ),
                        '10_5' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '2',
                            'item' => 'dvd',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '5'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

You can see some items are with different `shopid` and it's not sort.

How can delete, for example, those items with `shopid=4` from my basket?

Comment: Still consider changing architecture to use shop id as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple loop and built in PHP array functions:

```
$deleteShopId = 4;
$test = Array('customer' => Array('basket' => Array(
                    '9_2' => Array
                        (
                            "row" => "0",
                            'item' => 'cd',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '1391-12-25 19:27:56',
                            'sale_end_date' => '1392-04-20 19:27:49',
                            'sale_price' => '40500',
                            'price' => '54564',
                            'id' => '999035',
                            'shopid' => '4'
                        ),
                        '999_17' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '1',
                            'item' => 'car',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '6'
                        ),
                        '9_3' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '2',
                            'item' => 'book',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '4'
                        ),
                        '10_5' => Array
                        (
                            'row' => '2',
                            'item' => 'dvd',
                            'count' => '1',
                            'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                            'sale_price' => '0',
                            'price' => '520000',
                            'id' => '999039',
                            'code' => 'b125nh',
                            'shopid' => '5'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );

foreach($test['customer']['basket'] as $something => $somethingElse){
$temp = array_search($deleteShopId,$somethingElse);
   if($temp !== FALSE && $temp =='shopid'){
      unset($test['customer']['basket'][$something]);
   }
}

var_dump($test['customer']['basket']);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["999_17"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["row"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(3) "car"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sale_start_date"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["sale_end_date"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["sale_price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "520000"
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "999039"
    ["code"]=>
    string(6) "b125nh"
    ["shopid"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  ["10_5"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["row"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["item"]=>
    string(3) "dvd"
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sale_start_date"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["sale_end_date"]=>
    string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    ["sale_price"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "520000"
    ["id"]=>
    string(6) "999039"
    ["code"]=>
    string(6) "b125nh"
    ["shopid"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Of course rename $something and $somethingElse to something more meaningful. I have no idea what they represent.

Comment: That will delete *any* items which have *any* value equal to `4`, not just `shopid`!

Comment: Ha! you're right let me fix that, a simple string check on the conditional should do it.

Comment: i have question  array_search always return key number but in this case return value why ?

Comment: In this case he has an associative array so the key value is 'shop id' If this was just an array it would return a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$shop = 4;

$_SESSION['customer']['basket'] = array_filter(
    $_SESSION['customer']['basket'],
    function (array $item) use ($shop) { return $item['shopid'] != $shop; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively search your basket and get all keys with specific `shop_id`. For example this function:

```
function array_search_recursive($needle, $haystack, $key = false, $path = null) { 
    if(empty($path['level'])) $path['level'] = 0; 
    if(empty($path['work'])) $path['work'] = array(); 
    if(!is_array($haystack)) $haystack = array(); 

    foreach($haystack as $_key => $_value) { 
        if(is_scalar($_value) && $_value == $needle && !$key) { 
            $path['work'][$path['level']] = $_key; 
            $path['found'][] = $path['work']; 
        } elseif(is_scalar($_value) && $_value == $needle && $_key == $key) { 
            $path['work'][$path['level']] = $_key; 
            $path['found'][] = $path['work']; 
        } elseif (is_array($_value)) { 
            $path['work'][$path['level']] = $_key; 
            $path['level'] += 1; 
            $path = array_search_recursive($needle, $_value, $key, $path); 
        } 
    } 

    array_splice($path['work'], $path['level']); 
    $path['level'] -= 1; 

    if($path['level'] == '-1') {
        return $path['found'];
    } else return $path;
```

}

Would upon calling `array_search_recursive('4', $_SESSION['customer']['basket'])` return

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9_2
            [1] => shopid
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9_3
            [1] => shopid
        )

)
```

Then you can loop your basket and delete those keys. Also there are other ways of doing it, for example with `array_filter` like deceze suggested.

Code to unset the keys:

```
$keys = array_search_recursive('4', $_SESSION['customer']['basket']);
if(!empty($keys)) {
    foreach($keys as $item) {
        unset($_SESSION['customer']['basket'][$item[0]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd hope that the array has a defined structure, there should be no need to search recursively. Overcomplicate much? ;-P

Comment: If I create the structure, I know it will have defined structure. :) It might be a little complicated, its just one of many possible answers

Comment: it's not use full . i want unset each items with same shop id from my session

Comment: Of course, the code to unset them is not included. See updated answer

Comment: dear realshadow thanks alot for your help but it's not answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You might probably need to do somthing like this:

```
function selectUniqueByAttribute($array, $attributeName)
{
    $keysArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
        $keysArray[$value[$attributeName]] = $key;
    }

    $output = array();
    foreach($keysArray as $key){
        $output[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    return $output;
}
$data = array('customer' =>  array(
                'basket' => array(
                        '9_2' => array
                            (
                                "row" => "0",
                                'item' => 'cd',
                                'count' => '1',
                                'sale_start_date' => '1391-12-25 19:27:56',
                                'sale_end_date' => '1392-04-20 19:27:49',
                                'sale_price' => '40500',
                                'price' => '54564',
                                'id' => '999035',
                                'shopid' => '4'
                            ),
                            '999_17' => array
                            (
                                'row' => '1',
                                'item' => 'car',
                                'count' => '1',
                                'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                'sale_price' => '0',
                                'price' => '520000',
                                'id' => '999039',
                                'code' => 'b125nh',
                                'shopid' => '6'
                            ),
                            '9_3' => array
                            (
                                'row' => '2',
                                'item' => 'book',
                                'count' => '1',
                                'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                'sale_price' => '0',
                                'price' => '520000',
                                'id' => '999039',
                                'code' => 'b125nh',
                                'shopid' => '4'
                            ),
                            '10_5' => array
                            (
                                'row' => '2',
                                'item' => 'dvd',
                                'count' => '1',
                                'sale_start_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                'sale_end_date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                                'sale_price' => '0',
                                'price' => '520000',
                                'id' => '999039',
                                'code' => 'b125nh',
                                'shopid' => '5'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );

$filteredArray = array(
                    'customer'  =>  array(
                                            'basket'    =>  selectUniqueByAttribute($data['customer']['basket'], 'shopid')
                                         )
                  );
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($filteredArray);
die();
```